# Call function every minute in Stenciljs

Tags: typescript, setinterval, stenciljs

Is it possible to call a function every minute in a Stenciljs component. 
I want basically do this:

```
  setInterval(() => { this.checkSomeStuff() }, 60000);
```

But the problem is that Stenciljs cant handle it. It's not possible to just set the function like that. Should I use @Method, @Event, @Listen or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be a tricky problem but that depends on what you want to achieve.

Simon Hänisch already perfectly pointed out that you can use the Lifecycle Methods of a component. `componentWillLoad` to start the Interval and `componentDidUnload` would be a good choice.

But notice that Stenciljs renders your components only if necessary. That also means they get removed when Stencil "thinks" they are not longer needed. Than the whole code of your component is like removed which also of course stops your setInterval.

When you have a interval of 60 seconds i could imagine that the user maybe scrolls or do some other stuff that may your component will be unloaded and when the user than goes back to your component the interval starts again from zero. (Thats why I said in the beginning *maybe tricky* because in some cases this behaviour is fine in some not).

If not - you maybe need to store your interval and than start from where it stopped. For this maybe a static variable would be sufficient.

But maybe the best approach could be that you use the **@Method** decorator.

```
  @Method()
  checkSomeStuff() {
    // check stuff
  }
```

This makes the method of your component global available and you can call it in your index.html e.g. like this:

*index.html*

```
<your-component id="comp"></your-component>
<script>
  document.getElementById("comp").checkSomeStuff(); // yes you can call the function in that way
</script>
```

This gives you the possibility to run the SetInterval in the index.html.

Comment: What I want to do is to refresh a token that expires every hour. So I want to check if the token is close to expire (every minut or so), if it is less than 5 min remaining, refresh the token. 

So if a user goes away for 40 minuts and then come back, maybe the token have expired, because nothing have happend on the page and no event will be fired if I use component life cycles?

Comment: I tried your example with @Method and put the intervall in the index.html. It seems to work. Maybe not the prettiest solution, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

@Christian Meyer had a point. There are options to update it from outside or inside of the component. I strongly recommend do outside way.
The only thing I can add don't forget all methods recommended to be a Promise:
https://stenciljs.com/docs/methods

```
import { Method } from '@stencil/core';

export class TodoList {

  @Method()
  async showPrompt() {
    // show a prompt
  }
}
```

```
(async () => {
  await customElements.whenDefined('todo-list');
  const todoListElement = document.querySelector('todo-list');
  await todoListElement.showPrompt();
})();
```

Also consider a way of update based on data binding.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the interval in one of the component life cycles, e. g. `componentWillLoad`:

```
@Component({ tag: 'my-comp' })
export class MyComp {
  interval: any;

  componentWillLoad() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => { this.checkSomeStuff() }, 60000);
  }

  componentDidUnload() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  checkSomeStuff() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return <Host />;
  }
}
```

Full list of life cycle methods: https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle

Comment: Its a good idé, but maybe not exactly ok for my situation. I will use this to check if a token is expired or not, so even if the page is unused for 50 minuts (maybe user is on a break) I want to check the token every minut and that would not be possible with this solution, right?